# Stm32 Advanced timers Complementary channels can be individually controlled?

Tags: pwm

I need to design a device that generates up to 25 independent PWM outputs, and the four normal timers and two advanced timers of the stm32f103vc can generate 24 independent PWM outputs, so I can see if you can use the advanced timer Of the complementary PWM channels used as independent PWM outputs?
For example, **TIM1 CH1** and **CH1N** output can be complementary interference?
Whether they can produce independent PWM outputs？
Thank you！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channels for complementary interface cannot produce independent outputs. So **CHxN** can't be used as standalone output.

You can verify with number of output channel (OC) registers your advanced timer has (**TIM1** or **TIM8**)

Keep in mind, that with `four normal` and `2 advanced` timers you can't get your result, because they are not independent. All channels on one timer have the same frequency. If this is what you want, then you have independent channels, otherwise you don't have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！I still do not understand the point, I hope you can guide me. An advanced timer at the same frequency (the same PWM period), which 7 channels can output different duty cycle PWM?

Comment: I don't know where you saw that, but as far I know, up to 4 OC on each channels are possible.